# In pythons self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://google.com/")

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-grid

In pythons self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://google.com/") 
how do i run my python scripts from my desktop but my selenium rc is installed in main server.can i give my server location in place of localhost...please provide me the soultion ASAP. Thx
I am able to run my scripts in localhost selelnium rc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read more about selenium-grid from [here](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/). To use the grid, you should

1. start the hub and RC in server and client machines.
2. Register your RC to the Hub.
3. Then change the "localhost" in  `self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://google.com/")`

All the commands you pass to selenium grid will be distributed among the RCs that are registered to the Hub.

Always remember, selenium grid just executes multiple selenium commands. You should find a way by which multiple commands/tests can be triggered simultaneously

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback.
I already installed selenium grid and able to run hub and remote  control in different command prompt.
while executing python scripts for internet explorer.is that i need to change my port no ex 5556 instead of 4444 in my test cases.self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 5556, "*firefox", "http://google.com/"). 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are correct.Selenium RC is a client server technology.so we can place client and server in different machines.

this is how we usually run test scripts against number of browsers(browser testing) in different machines.

cheers

Comment: Thanks Sudharshan.                                                                      what is too many clients wants to execute python scripts from the server.i think selenium grid is very good option, but i dont know how to execute python scripts using selenium grid.not able to find the answer in google too. Thx.

Comment: please anyone provide me the solution ASAP. Thx

Comment: you dont' have to use GRID just to run the scripts remotely.follow the steps 1) copy the selenium server jar file into the machine where ever you want to run the scripts.